# Structured Type to match Class Constructor

Tags: scala, reflection, manifest, duck-typing

Is it possible to create a structured type ins scala to match a class constructor (as opposed to method/function definitions in a class)

To normally match a method call for a class, you would do something like this

```
type SomeType : {def someMethod:String}
```

Which allows you to make some method that goes like this

```
someMethod(a:SomeType) = {
    println(a.someMethod)
}
```

What would the equivalent be for something like this

```
type AnotherType: {.......}
```

Which would work with something like this

```
class UserId(val id:Long) extends AnyVal
```

So you can then do something like this

```
anotherMethod(a:AnotherType,id:Long):AnotherType = {
    new a(id)
}

anotherMethod(UserId,3) // Will return an instance of UserId(3)
```

I believe this is possible using manifest using runtimeClass and getConstructors, however I am wondering if this is possible using more cleanly (by using something like structured types)

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so I suppose its you just need to use reflection with manifest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reflection or structural types, consider using your types companion object as a function value,

```
scala> case class UserId(val id: Long) extends AnyVal
defined class UserId

scala> def anotherMethod[T, U](ctor: T => U, t: T) = ctor(t)
anotherMethod: [T, U](ctor: T => U, t: T)U

scala> anotherMethod(UserId, 3L)
res0: UserId = UserId(3)
```

This works as shown for case classes because the Scala compiler will automatically provide the companion object with an `apply` method which invokes the classes primary constructor and it will also arrange for the companion to extend the appropriate `FunctionN` trait.

If, for whatever reason, your type can't be a case class you can provide the apply method yourself,

```
object UserId extends (Long => UserId) {
  def apply(l: Long) = new UserId(l)
}
```

or you can use a function literal at call sites instead,

```
anotherMethod(new UserId(_: Long), 3L)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Thankfully converting my UserId's to case classes didn't break anything!

Comment: It would also explain my approach didn't work, there wasn't any equivalent companion object (never knew that case classes provided a default companion object). Something new to learn!